# REST proxy for a SOAP Web Service: can I reuse the JAXB classes for the input/output JSON?

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, soap, jaxb

I'm creating a proxy service for translating an existing SOAP Web Service to REST. I mean, to create a REST Controller based on Spring for creating the REST interface that will call the existing SOAP Web Service.
The SOAP response must be translated into JSON on the REST service's response.

The steps I followed were:

1. I have generated the SOAP WebService classes thanks to CXF
   (*wsdl2java*). OK.
2. I have created the REST Controller for invoking the existing SOAP WS with the previous classes. OK.
3. The input JSON parameter corresponds to the SOAP input parameter. Can I reuse the JAXB classes I generated on the *wsdl2java* process?

So I tried to define the REST controller as:

```
public @ResponseBody WebServiceJAXBOutput service(@RequestBody WebServiceJAXBInput input){
...
}
```

Nevertheless, the REST call always returns 400 (Bad request) if I specify the data values. Although it works if the input JSON fields are null:

```
{
 "application":null,
 "center":null,
 "language":null
}
```

I guess the JAXB getter/setters are failing because of the JAXBElement (*public JAXBElement getApplication()*).

Should this approach work? Did I miss something?

Many thanks!!
Sergi